# how to retrieve a string from an NSArray of strings

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an NSArray of strings. I have to place each string in a cell of a table. How to get the string of the array into an NSString ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use -[NSArray objectAtIndex: index] to retrieve an object from an array. Also read the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).